# Sharepoint UserProfileManager without Manage User Profiles right

Tags: c#, sharepoint

I have an issue that is driving me a bit nuts: Using a UserProfileManager as an non-authorized user.

The problem: The user does not have "Manage User Profiles" rights, but I still want to use the UserProfileManager. The idea of using SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges does not seem to work, as the UserProfileManager authorizes against the SSP as it seems.

```
            SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(delegate()
            {
                using (SPSite site = new SPSite(inputWeb.Site.ID))
                {
                    ServerContext ctx = ServerContext.GetContext(site);
                    UserProfileManager upm = new UserProfileManager(ctx,true);
                    UserProfile u = upm.GetUserProfile(userLogin);
                    DepartmentName = u["Department"].Value as string;
                }
            });
```

This still fails on the "new UserProfileManager" line, with the "You must have manage user profiles administrator rights to use administrator mode" exception.

As far as I userstood, RunWithElevatedPrivileges reverts to the AppPool Identity. WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name returns "NT AUTHORITY\network service", and I have given that account Manage User Profiles rights - no luck.

site.RootWeb.CurrentUser.LoginName returns SHAREPOINT\system for the site created within RunWithElevatedPrivileges, which is not a valid Windows Account ofc.

Is there even a way to do that? I do not want to give all users "Manage User Profiles" rights, but I just want to get some data from the user profiles (Department, Country, Direct Reports). Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The permission that needs set is actually found in the Shared Service Provider.

1. Navigate to Central Admin
2. Navigate to the Shared Service Provider
3. Under **User Profiles and My Sites** navigate to Personalization services permissions .
4. If the account doesn't already exist, add the account for which your sites App Domain is running under.
5. Grant that user **Manage user profiles** permission.

I notice that you're running the application pool under the Network Service account.  I implemented an identical feature on my site; however, the application pool was hosted under a Windows account.  I'm not sure why this would make a difference, however.

Comment: That does not seem to work for Network Service. On the Weekend, i'll try if it works with a domain account. Using a Domain Account is recommended anyway AFAIK, but my Dev Machine is a Standalone server.

Comment: Interesting.  I'll check back at this post after this weekend.  If it still doesn't work, leave me another comment and I'll see what I can dig up. Your code looks fine and I know this works because I've done it in the past.

Answer (score 2):

There are two ways I've actually managed to accomplish this:

1. Put the code that uses the UserProfileManager behind a web services layer. The web service should use an application pool identity that has access to the User Profile services.
2. Use the impersonation technique describe in the following article:
   http://www.dotnetjunkies.com/WebLog/victorv/archive/2005/06/30/128890.aspx

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for the Answers. One Caveat: if you run the Application Pool as "Network Service" instead of a Domain Account, you're screwed.

But then again, it's recommended to use a domain account anyway (On a test server I used network service, but after changing it to a domain account it worked).

Comment: Yes, that's what I've come to after a day of attempts to revert impersonation to NETWORK SERVICE and then create a user profile property, it all ends in a native method which doesn't give you the permission.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the answer. Its a stupid Microsoft bug, and there is a hotfix. I'm downloading now to test it.

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/952294/en-us

Comment: Thanks. Going to check that out as well soon.